# migration Aura to Lightning Web Components Open Source

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, open-source

I am looking for some method which can convert pre built Aura components to LWC open source.

is there any tool or simple convert method exist?

I wish I don't have to do it one by one.

Comment: There is no such tools exist as of now, it needs to be done manually

Comment: I see, I wonder if I can refer web page which explaining the procedure.
Such a page also doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Migrate Aura Components to Lightning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_introduction) contains the full documentation on undertaking this

[Migration Strategy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_strategy) mentions that you're not likely to want to convert line-by-line - but, rather evaluate your design and how it would work best considering the differences in the two models.

> **The programming model for Lightning Web Components is fundamentally different than the model for Aura components. Migrating a component is not a line-by-line conversion, and it's a good opportunity to revisit your component's design**. Before you migrate an Aura component, evaluate the component’s attributes, interfaces, structures, patterns, and data flow

> After migrating one component, you'll be in a better position to determine whether it makes sense for you and your org to:

> - Undertake a larger migration effort
> - Use Lightning web components for new components only
> - Stick with Aura components for now

It then has specific pages dedicated to migrating the various parts:

- [Migrate Markup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_markup)
- [Migrate Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_events)
- [Interfaces](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_interfaces)
- [CSS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_css)
- [Javascript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_javascript)
- [Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_apex)

Of the above, some are more straightforward than others. As an example, apex methods have no syntax differences - but, Lightning Web Components can also use the JavaScript `@wire` decorator to wrap calls to an Apex method or the User Interface API

Likewise, there's other differences to consider

- [Data binding](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_data_binding)

  - LWC data binding between components for property values is one-way
- [Base Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_map_aura_lwc_components)

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know this.

Answer (score 0):

I recently built a tool to do this:

https://aura-to-lwc.herokuapp.com/

There are still many bugs, but at the same time it does provide some of the necessary features. It can be performed in two ways:

- Login to your org, select which Aura components to convert, and download the converted LWC components
- Copy & paste your Aura code into the playground and click Convert button to see the converted LWC code immediately

Comment: HI FlyGuy, and welcome to SFSE. Please read up on the guidelines on [self promotion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). You are doing a good job disclosing your affiliation, but if all your posts here are self-promotion, that can still cause you to be identified as a spammer in the long run. Sounds like you have some good knowledge to share on tags such as `[lwc]` and others related to lightning. Consider browsing for some questions you can help out on where your tool doesn't apply!